# Apple mach -o- Linker Error

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to IOS development and i tried to resolve the error but nothing works. Provide some suggestion.

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-XXXXXXX-AppInvites
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image]

Comment: sorry but i didnt get what you meant to state.

Comment: haha, jokes apart. is that any solution to my problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the project using workspace (that was generated by CocoaPods) instead of the xcodeproj. I think this will resolve your issue. Otherwise there may be some library missing in CocoaPods.

[image]

Comment: In your project, there are two icons project.workspace and project.xcodeproj. Open the project using workspace icon. Not the xcodeproj icon.

Comment: @SahebRoy I can open the project and the errors are also solved but couldnot test on either device or simulator.. how can i make it happen?